# A finger is a component of a hand, a hand is the X of a finger

Tags: terminology, vocabulary, generic-term, taxonomy

I'm working with a set of relationships between things, relationships that need descriptors.

> John is a *child* of Susan, Susan is a *parent* of John; a *parent-child* relationship.
>
> Milk is a *product* of cows, cows are a *source* of milk; a *source-product* relationship.
>
> A finger is a *component* of a hand, a hand is the __ of a finger; a __*-component* relationship.

This gap could be filled by an unwieldy phrase like, "thing that is comprised of other things, such as", but I'd much rather use a single word instead.

Is there a word that can fill the gap in my example sentence?

Comment: Well **part-whole** is shorter than component-X.  But if doesn't really add anything meaningwise.

Comment: @Oldcat, *whole* unfortunately doesn't work.  You wouldn't say a hand is the whole of a finger.

Comment: It just shows that your construction isn't universal.  Even your Cow example is wrong.  Milk and leather have no relation at all, source/product or otherwise.

Comment: I feel like "leather" is just a distraction. You could perfectly say "Milk is a product of cows, cows are a source of milk," with that being a source-product relationship.

Comment: Constructions in Engish are not always perfectly reversable and adding a hyphen between them in front of relationship isn't very meaningful.

Comment: *Leather* was entirely spurious, it should have been *milk*.

Comment: Would *assembly* work for you? It sounds mechanical, but so does *component*.

Answer (score 5):

There is no general purpose  way of going from the formulation "A is a part of B" to "B is a (blank) of A".

Even in semantics, this "B is a (blank) of A" is described as "B has an A".

This can be seen in the discussions of the semantic-relationship between the names of objects, using the terms *meronym* and *holonym*.

[Meronymy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meronymy) and [holonymy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonymy) cover the cases like

- X is a part of Y
- X has a Y

by referring the relationship between the names of X and Y:

"X" is a meronym of "Y" if Xs are parts of Ys

"X" is a holonym of "Y" if Ys are parts of Xs (Xs have Ys)

Strictly speaking, this relationship is about the words themselves and how they describe the relationships between their corresponding objects.

So:
The word "finger" is a meronym of the word "hand" if fingers are parts of hands.
The word "hand" is a holonym of the word "finger" if hands have fingers.

But my point is, even in semantics, there is no other way to describe the relationship between the objects rather than the form "A has a B".

Of course there are specific cases where there are words. *Parent-Child" is one of them. There are others: *Part-Whole*; *Source-Product*, as examples.

Comment: So the word "hand" is a holonym of the word "finger", but an actual hand is not a holonym of an actual finger?

Comment: Yes. It is about the relationship of the objects, but homonym and meronym refers to the names of the objects.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly question your categories here as not logical. E.g.:

> Milk is a product of cows, cows are a source of leather; a source-product relationship.

Milk and leather are both products, with no relationship other than that. Alligator leather has nothing in common with milk, save that it is an animal product. Eggs are animal products; they have nothing in common with leather, except for being animal products. Your category is illogical.

> A finger is a component of a hand, a hand is the __ of a finger; a __-component relationship.

The finger is indeed a part or component of the hand; the hand is the whole, which contains all the parts.

Comment: Good catch -- where it said *leather* it should have said *milk*.  I must have changed my mind while writing it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider: *the hand is the **possessor** of the finger*. The thing that *has* the component is the component's *possessor*.

> **Possessor** *noun*
>   one who has a legal or rightful claim to ownership 
>   [- M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/possessor)

Note that the dictionary definition is cast in a legal setting, but here's a title that serves as an example along the lines of the part-whole concept (emphasis mine):

> **Skin** of the dorsal aspect of human hands and fingers **possesses** an **active vasodilator system**.
>   [- Johnson JM1, Pérgola PE, Liao FK, Kellogg DL Jr, Crandall CG.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7775340)

Synonyms of *possessor* include *owner* and, interestingly, *holder*.